# Conflicts from a sonic perspective

Tags: sound, broadcasting, war

I thought some of you would be interested in this from the BBC,[link text](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-20400030) its a history of conflicts from more of a sonic perspective. The sounds of conflict are obviously some of the most powerful sounds that man has made and get lodged in the memory whether you are a civilian or soldier as a matter of survival. When my grandad came back from the war for many years he would dive to the ground if he heard a car backfire and I am sure many involved in today's wars are in many ways affected just as much by the sonic aspect as the visual.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be the sound of the drone is greatly feared in that part of the world right now.